# How to determine if directory is a symbolic link

Tags: node.js, fs

I ran `fs.lstat` and I get these stats for a directory:

```
Stats {
  dev: 16777220,
  mode: 16877,
  nlink: 8,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 7366885,
  size: 272,
  blocks: 0,
  atime: 2017-04-16T23:18:17.000Z,
  mtime: 2017-04-16T23:14:49.000Z,
  ctime: 2017-04-16T23:14:49.000Z,
  birthtime: 2017-04-16T23:14:49.000Z }
```

How I can determine if this directory is a symbolic link?

Comment: Check the `isSymbolicLink` method https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

Comment: thanks, I thought that util.inspect() would capture those methods if they existed, not sure why it didn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was logging the stats object with

```
util.inspect(stats);
```

but the methods for the stats object are on the `__proto__` of the object:

`stats.isSymbolicLink()` is the call to use

You want to use `fs.lstat()` instead of `fs.stat()`, as the former will not follow the symbolic link. If you follow the symbolic link, eventually you will get to an actual directory, which would mean `stats.isSymbolicLink()` would always return false. But that's not really what we are looking for.

**So the answer is:**

```
fs.lstat(<path>, function(err,stats){

     if(stats.isSymbolicLink()){
          // do your thing
      }

});
```

Comment: This is so silly of node, having the method `isSymbolicLink()` in 2 places, but works only in one of 'em! I just bumped into it...!